# Where is code refers to /proc/PID/maps?

Tags: linux-kernel, mmu

I what to observe kernel code to print `/proc/PID/maps` but can't find this. Could anybody tell me where this code is located

Answer (score 7):

The procfs code can be found in `fs/proc/` subdirectory. If you open `fs/proc/base.c`, you can find two very similar arrays - `tgid_base_stuff` and `tid_base_stuff`. They both register file operations functions for files inside of `/proc/PID/` and `/proc/PID/TID/` respectivly. So you're more interested in the first one. Find the one that registers `"maps"` file, it looks like this:

```
REG("maps",       S_IRUGO, proc_pid_maps_operations),
```

So the structure describing file operations on this file is called `proc_pid_maps_operations`. This function is defined in two places - `fs/proc/task_mmu.c` and `fs/proc/task_nommu.c`. Which one is actually used depends on your kernel configuration but it's most likely the first one.

Inside of `task_mmu.c`, you can find the structure definition:

```
const struct file_operations proc_pid_maps_operations =
{
    .open       = pid_maps_open,
    .read       = seq_read,
    .llseek     = seq_lseek,
    .release    = proc_map_release,
};
```

So when `/proc/PID/maps` is opened, the kernel will use `pid_maps_open` function, which registers another set of operations:

```
static const struct seq_operations proc_pid_maps_op = {
    .start  = m_start,
    .next   = m_next,
    .stop   = m_stop,
    .show   = show_pid_map
};
```

So you're interested in `show_pid_map` function, which only calls `show_map` function which in turn calls `show_map_vma` (all in the same file).

Answer (score 2):

It's the `show_pid_map()` function in `fs/proc/task_mmu.c` (provided your system uses an MMU, which is the case of most non-embedded systems).

In general, the code for files under `/proc/` can be cause under `fs/procfs`.